# Adding Items dynamically with dependant select options that fetch from the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, mysql

I have created a form like this that fetches data from the database

```
<select name="notelinecategory" id="category"class="form-control sl" required="true" onChange="getdistrict(this.value);">
                <option value="<?php echo $row['nc_id'];?>">Select Diagnosis</option>
                    <?php $query =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM notelinecategory");
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                        { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['nc_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['category'];?></option>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                                                
            </select></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col">

            <select name="noteline[]" class="form-control sl" required="true" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple"  id="notelines" style="height: 100px">
                <option value=""></option>
                    
            </select>
```

The above fetches data and adds dynamically to a text area.
I want to insert multiple field's data to the database and i find it hard to capture options from the dependent dropdown list. Here is my script:

```
$('#addrow').click(function(){
                var length = $('.sl').length;
                var i   = parseInt(length)+parseInt(1);
                var newrow = $('#next').append('<div class="wrap-content container" id="container'+i+'"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="panel-body"><p style="color:red;"><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['msg']);?>
                    <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['msg']="");?></p><form><div class="form-group align-self-start"><label for="notelinecategory">Choose a Diagnosis</label><select name="notelinecategory" class="form-control" required="true" id="category'+i+'"onChange="getdistrict(this.value);"><option value="<?php echo $row['nc_id'];?>'+i+'">Select Diagnosis</option><?php $query =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM notelinecategory");
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                            { ?><option value="<?php echo $row['nc_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['category'];?></option>                                     <?php } ?>
                            </select></div><div class="form-group"><div class="col"><select name="noteline[]'+i+'" class="form-control" required="true" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple"  id="notelines'+i+'" style="height: 100px"><option value=""></option></select></div></div></form></div>                       </div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="panel-body"><p style="color:red;"><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['msg']);?>
                    <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['msg']="");?></p><form role="form" name="notelines'+i+'" method="post"><label for="Select_patients">select Patient Name                   </label><select name="PatientName'+i+'" class="form-control" required="true">                   <option value="'+i+'">Select Patient</option>                       <?php
                        $docid=$_SESSION['id'];
                        $ret=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tblpatient where Docid='$docid'");
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret))
                        {
                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['PatientName']);?>">                            <?php echo htmlentities($row['PatientName']);?>
                            </option>                                       <?php } ?>
                            </select><br><textarea id="CAPoutput'+i+'" rows="4" cols="75" name="notelines"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['textentered']) && $_SESSION['textentered'] !=''){echo $_SESSION['textentered'];} ?></textarea><input type="button" class="btnRemove btn-danger" value="Remove"/></div><br>');
        
                        });
                    
                    // Removing event here
                  $('body').on('click','.btnRemove',function() {
                       $(this).closest('div').remove()  });
```

Comment: youre doing inline database queries...?

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to add multiple data in the same table using dynamically generated fields. The part that is not working is the script is not duplicating all the fields as-is from the select options